# Make first child link default instead of its parent

Tags: php, links

I want to do something like this: if a parent have kids get page link of the first child else get page link of itself. For example:

Page 1

- Sub-page 1 (**get this link**)
- Sub-page 2
- Sub-page 3

Page 2 (**get this link**)

Page 3

- Sub-page 1 (**get this link**)
- Sub-page 2

Page 4 (**get this link**)

Comment: Which function are you using? `wp_list_pages`, `wp_page_menu`, `wp_nav_menu`? Or a custom `foreach` loop/walker?

Comment: this is my cod:

$mykids = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&sort_column=menu_order&parent='.$post->ID);

foreach( $mykids as $page ) {?>
<a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></a>